# Why can't I see block 1 on my local validator?

Tags: validator, local-cluster, localnet

I have `solana-test-validator` running locally.

And from https://explorer.solana.com, I can pick 'Custom RPC URL' and see the stats for my local validator. Clicking on the link for the current slot, I get https://explorer.solana.com/block/235965?cluster=custom&customUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8899

So far everything is fine.

If I manually change the URL to be https://explorer.solana.com/block/1?cluster=custom&customUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8899

I get:

> Failed to fetch block

**Why can't I see block I on my local validator?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TestValidator doesn't keep ledger around forever. It is likely slot 1 was already pruned from yours.
If you want to see what slots and roots you have locally, you can run `solana-ledger-tool bounds -l <PATH_TO_YOUR_TEST_VALIDATOR>/test-ledger`.